# Close open HTML tags in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

Situation is a string that results in something like this:

```
<p>This is some text and here is a <strong>bold text then the post stop here....</p>
```

Because the function returns a teaser (summary) of the text, it stops after certain words. Where in this case the tag strong is not closed. But the whole string is wrapped in a paragraph.

Is it possible to convert the above result/output to the following:

```
<p>This is some text and here is a <strong>bold text then the post stop here....</strong></p>
```

I do not know where to begin. The problem is that.. I found a function on the web which does it regex, but it puts the closing tag after the string.. therefore it won't validate because I want all open/close tags within the paragraph tags. The function I found does this which is wrong also:

```
<p>This is some text and here is a <strong>bold text then the post stop here....</p></strong>
```

I want to know that the tag can be strong, italic, anything. That's why I cannot append the function and close it manually in the function. Any pattern that can do it for me?

Comment: can't you just add the closing tags in your teaser function?

Comment: The teaser gets html (formatted) input from user. I can not add it because the tag could be anything else.. italic.. strong so on. I thought it would be better if we search open tags at the end of the output then close them..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is a function i've used before, which works pretty well:

```
function closetags($html) {
    preg_match_all('#<(?!meta|img|br|hr|input\b)\b([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);
    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        } else {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Personally though, I would not do it using regexp but a library such as Tidy. This would be something like the following:

```
$str = '<p>This is some text and here is a <strong>bold text then the post stop here....</p>';
$tidy = new Tidy();
$clean = $tidy->repairString($str, array(
    'output-xml' => true,
    'input-xml' => true
));
echo $clean;
```

Comment: You know ! that regex did it.. no validation error or anything.

Comment: Yeah, that regexp works really well and is a good alternative if Tidy is not available.

Comment: Can I ask about Tidy thing. Is it available on all servers? Some clients still rely on php4.. is this ok ? or it's something that can be attached to script.. ? :)

Comment: Thank you kindly for introducing me to Tidy. It is a many splendored thing :)

Comment: @alexn, could you please elaborate why you use `output-xml` and not `output-html` or `output-xhtml` to convert?

Comment: Excellent, but what about with those tags which have more than one character? such as `<h1>` `<span>` etc. I think the **closetags function** can't close them.

Comment: `$pos_l = strripos($html, '<'); $pos_lc = strripos($html, '>'); if ($pos_l > $pos_lc) { $html = substr($html, 0, $pos_l); }` To remove trailing `<` tags.

Answer (score 10):

A small modification to the original answer...while the original answer stripped tags correctly. I found that during my truncation, I could end up with chopped up tags. For example:

```
This text has some <b>in it</b>
```

Truncating at character 21 results in:

```
This text has some <
```

The following code, builds on the next best answer and fixes this.

```
function truncateHTML($html, $length)
{
    $truncatedText = substr($html, $length);
    $pos = strpos($truncatedText, ">");
    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $html = substr($html, 0,$length + $pos + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        $html = substr($html, 0,$length);
    }

    preg_match_all('#<(?!meta|img|br|hr|input\b)\b([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];

    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
    $closedtags = $result[1];

    $len_opened = count($openedtags);

    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened)
    {
        return $html;
    }

    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++)
    {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags))
        {
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        }
        else
        {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }


    return $html;
}


$str = "This text has <b>bold</b> in it</b>";
print "Test 1 - Truncate with no tag: " . truncateHTML($str, 5) . "<br>\n";
print "Test 2 - Truncate at start of tag: " . truncateHTML($str, 20) . "<br>\n";
print "Test 3 - Truncate in the middle of a tag: " . truncateHTML($str, 16) . "<br>\n";
print "Test 4: - Truncate with less text: " . truncateHTML($str, 300) . "<br>\n";
```

Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: @Marcus I would like to know the initialization of $result parameter inside the preg_match_All()

Comment: It was way long back when I was working on joomla. I don't remember the result now.

Answer (score 5):

And what about using PHP's native DOMDocument class? It inherently parses HTML and corrects syntax errors...
E.g.:

```
$fragment = "<article><h3>Title</h3><p>Unclosed";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($fragment);
$correctFragment = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->C14N();
echo $correctFragment;
```

However, there are several disadvantages of this approach.
Firstly, it wraps the original fragment within the `<body>` tag. You can get rid of it easily by something like (preg_)replace() or by substituting the `...->C14N()` function by some custom innerHTML() function, as suggested for example at http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89718.
The second pitfall is that PHP throws an 'invalid tag in Entity' warning if HTML5 or custom tags are used (nevertheless, it will still proceed correctly).

Comment: Note that this `C14n()` destroys multibyte strings.

Comment: Correction: `loadHTML()` already [doesn't support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#74777) multibyte strings / UTF-8 out of the box. Use this extra step: `@$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($fragment, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 4):

This PHP method always worked for me. It will close all un-closed HTML tags.

```
function closetags($html) {
    preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];

    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);
    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)){
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        } else {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous other variables that need to be addressed to give a full solution, but are not covered by your question.

However, I would suggest using something like [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) and in particular the `repairFile` or `repaireString` methods.

Comment: The problem is that the string gets input as html formatted input, sometimes the teaser exits where one or more tags are open and not closed because the closing tags are in the full article.. i just want to close those open tags right before the teaser end. Thought regex could do that

Comment: You can use the HTML Tidy option. Regex is frowned upon when accessing HTML elements simply because parsing HTML is too irregular and encompassing all of its idiosyncrasies in regex is a monstrous task. I would recommend you at least try the HTML Tidy option...

Answer (score 1):

if tidy module is installed, use php tidy extension:

```
tidy_repair_string($html)
```

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression isn't an ideal approach for this. You should use an html parser instead to create a valid document object model.

As a second option, depending on what you want, you could use a regex to remove any and all html tags from your string before you put it in the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Why would you suggest a HTML parser in Python when there a PHP alternatives? The question **is** tagged PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this code witch doest the job quite correctly...

It's old school but efficient and I've added a flag to remove the unfinished tags such as " blah blah http://stackoverfl"

```
public function getOpennedTags(&$string, $removeInclompleteTagEndTagIfExists = true) {

    $tags = array();
    $tagOpened = false;
    $tagName = '';
    $tagNameLogged = false;
    $closingTag = false;

    foreach (str_split($string) as $c) {
        if ($tagOpened && $c == '>') {
            $tagOpened = false;
            if ($closingTag) {
                array_pop($tags);
                $closingTag = false;
                $tagName = '';
            }
            if ($tagName) {
                array_push($tags, $tagName);
            }
        }
        if ($tagOpened && $c == ' ') {
            $tagNameLogged = true;
        }
        if ($tagOpened && $c == '/') {
            if ($tagName) {
                //orphan tag
                $tagOpened = false;
                $tagName = '';
            } else {
                //closingTag
                $closingTag = true;
            }
        }
        if ($tagOpened && !$tagNameLogged) {
            $tagName .= $c;
        }
        if (!$tagOpened && $c == '<') {
            $tagNameLogged = false;
            $tagName = '';
            $tagOpened = true;
            $closingTag = false;
        }
    }

    if ($removeInclompleteTagEndTagIfExists && $tagOpened) {
        // an tag has been cut for exemaple ' blabh blah <a href="sdfoefzofk' so closing the tag will not help...
        // let's remove this ugly piece of tag
        $pos = strrpos($string, '<');
        $string = substr($string, 0, $pos);
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

Usage example :

```
$tagsToClose = $stringHelper->getOpennedTags($val);
$tagsToClose = array_reverse($tagsToClose);

foreach ($tagsToClose as $tag) {
    $val .= "</$tag>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me to close any open HTML tags in a script.

```
<?php
function closetags($html) {
preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
$openedtags = $result[1];
preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
$closedtags = $result[1];
$len_opened = count($openedtags);
if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
    return $html;
}
$openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
        $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
    } else {
        unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
    }
}
return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An up-to-date solution with parsing HTML would be:

```
function fix_html($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` is needed to avoid implementing doctype, html and body.. the rest looks pretty obvious :)

UPDATE:
After some testing noticed, that the solution above ruins a correct layout time-after-time. The following works well, though:

```
function fix_html($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );
    $return = '';
    foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'body' )->item(0)->childNodes as $v ) {
        $return .= $dom->saveHTML( $v );
    }
    return $return;
}
```