# Get the first 200 characters of a string without breaking HTML tags at the end

Tags: php, html

**EDIT**: The key point is about getting the first 200 characters and closing all tags, that are left open.

---

I'm currently loading articles from other website via DOM object (the other website have no RSS). I want to make a "preview" of that article, but here are my problems:

1. I do not control how the articles are written, therefore it seems to always be inside a table on the second TR (they use a CMS and it is messy - see example below).
2. They have A LOT of HTML tags, I don't want to leave one open.
3. I need to keep the HTML format, I know it's ugly but it fits perfectly in my page.

Not my code (in French sorry):

```
<table>

<TR >

<TD class='Normal' valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding-bottom:15px;">13-01-2012   <b>Water-polo – Championnat pan-pacifique<b ></TD>

</TR><TR >

<TD class='Normal' valign="top"><span class="HeadTitleNews"> Les Canadiennes disputeront le bronze aux Chinoises</span>   <img src='http://www.sportcom.qc.ca/Portals/0/2011WaterpoloF.jpg' width='165' align='right' class='imgAnnouncementCss'><div style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt"><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt">Montr&eacute;al, 13 janvier 2012 (Sportcom) &ndash; L&rsquo;&eacute;quipe f&eacute;minine canadienne de water-polo a remport&eacute; une victoire &eacute;crasante de 19-3 face au Br&eacute;sil, vendredi, au Championnat pan-pacifique de Melbourne, en Australie. Les Canadiennes se sont ainsi assur&eacute;es de participer au match pour la m&eacute;daille de bronze contre les Chinoises. </span></div>

<div style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt"><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt">La Montr&eacute;alaise <strong>Sophie</strong></span><strong><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt"> Baron-La Salle</span></strong><span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt"> a marqu&eacute; quatre buts dans la victoire. </span></div>

<div style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt">&nbsp;</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am confused as to what exactly you want.  Do you want to take the first 200 characters except ignoring everything after the first unclosed HTML tag, or do you want to take all of the first 200 characters and then add closing tags for any tags left open?

Comment: @BrooksMoses from my interpretation it seems like the OP wants to get the first 200 chars of plain text, but then add the HTML tags back in to preserve the formatting.

Comment: sry if i was unclear, the second option, getting the first 200 characters and closing the tags left open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to close open HTML tag in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php 
$your_string_without_tags = strip_tags($your_string); 
$your_200_char_string = substr($your_string_without_tags, 0, 200); 
?>
```

[Close open HTML tags in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strip_tags` function to remove all the html tags and then use it as you wish.

Comment: sry if i was unclear, the second option, getting the first 200 characters and closing the tags left open.

Comment: this... actually isn't actually an answer, as the point if to **keep** the html tags and close them, not **remove** them