# Cutting text in between destroys the design

Tags: php, css

I'm currently having an issue with my website. I count like 150 words and then cut it for displaying as an intro text on my website but this produces an issue.

When we have something like this in the text:

```
<div>
////TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT////
----> Reach 150 words here <------
////TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT////
</div>
```

It will print this in the front-page:

```
<div>
////TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT////
----> Reach 150 words here <------
```

and the unclosed `<div>` tag destroys the design as it is expected.

How can I overcome this issue? Can we like proccess unclosed tags and close them in the end?

Comment: Why you are keeping html tags in the first place ?

Comment: @UtkuYıldırım I'm not the author. The author is someone who doesn't know anything about this stuff and the formatting of the text does actually happen with tags! So I can't basically ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php's strip_tags to remove the div from your copy, then add it back in afterwards.

For example;

```
<?php
$html = '<div>Content goes here</div>';
$stripped = strip_tags($html);
$excerpt_pos = strpos(' ', $stripped, 150);
?>

<div><?php echo substr($stripped, 0, $excerpt_pos); ?></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is good. But, DIV tag is just an example. It could be any HTML tag with a closing tag. I think @Miro asked for a generic solution.

Comment: In that case he needs a regex or tidy. There's an answer for that here: [php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks I got my answer from the link!