# PHP Check For Matching Tags In User Submitted Content

Tags: php, tags, match, forum

I've been putting together my own customly made forum using PHP, and it's coming along astoundingly, but I was trying to figure out if there is a way to check for matching BBCode tags? I have my own arrays set up to replace `<b>` with `[b]` and so on, but I want to be able to make sure that the tags will be closed at some point `[/b]` and not continue to run off of the post and onto the rest of the page.

For example: `[b]This is text` will show up as `[b]This is text`, and `[b]This is text[/b]` will return on the page as `<b>This is text</b>`

Is there a way to do this, or is there a way in PHP/HTML to 'escape' any opened tags? IE; if no `[/b]` is in the post, automatically add a `</b>` onto the end of it.

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/3618/ 
http://htmlpurifier.org/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very simple bbcode parser for your requirement:

```php
function bbcode($data)
{
    $input = array(
        '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is',
        '/\[b\](.*?)$/',
    );
    $output = array(
        '<b>$1</b>',
        '<b>$1</b>',
    );
    return preg_replace ($input, $output, $data);;
}
```

some examples:

```
bbcode('[b]text[/]');
//returns <b>text</b>

bbcode('[b]text');
//returns <b>text</b>
```

See the example running [here](http://ideone.com/Wu6Fz1)

Comment: just a comment, for other tags you need to do the same, with the same regex.

Answer (score -1):

So here you want to parse out BBCode tags with HTML Tags, here's a small function I found over web that can do your job pretty easily

```
<?php

/* Simple PHP BBCode Parser function */

//BBCode Parser function

function showBBcodes($text) {

// BBcode array
$find = array(
'~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
'~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
'~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
'~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
'~\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/size\]~s',
'~\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/color\]~s',
'~\[url\]((?:ftp|https?)://.*?)\[/url\]~s',
'~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s'
);

// HTML tags to replace BBcode
$replace = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<i>$1</i>',
'<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
'<pre>$1</'.'pre>',
'<span style="font-size:$1px;">$2</span>',
'<span style="color:$1;">$2</span>',
'<a href="$1">$1</a>',
'<img src="$1" alt="" />'
);

// Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}

// How to use the above function:

$bbtext = "This is [b]bold[/b] and this is [u]underlined[/u] and this is in [i]italics[/i] with a [color=red] red color[/color]";
$htmltext = showBBcodes($bbtext);
echo $htmltext;

?>
```

Comment: this is not the answer that @TheElm is looking for. He says if the bbcode is not closed, add the corresponding closing tag at the end

Comment: The regex from this is really helpful, along with rogello's answer to have it close the tags after it is closed. Thanks for the answer!