# Changed formation while use character limit in TBS library

Tags: php, html, database, tinybutstrong

I fetch description from database(MySql). I store the description in html format. When i display description with char limit it cut some tag so the formation is change. So any idea how can i fix this problem.

In database description is store like:

```
<b>Hello</b><br/><p>This is my HTML code</p>
```

When I use string limit while displaying this description like limit=8 character then the Hello will come in bold but after hello world the all other content will come in bold.

Limit is 8 so it counts from database till `<b>Hello`.  This `</b>` will not be count so the `<b>` tag not over and the other content will come in bold.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/close-open-html-tags-in-a-string You can apply the function explained in the solution to close all tags of your string. So you just have to make sure you won't cut your string within a tag.