# How to automatically close tags in truncated paragraphs

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter page that displays the first 16 words of a product's description from a database. Users can change the description to include i tags and b tags using CKEditor. The problem is that when I truncate the description to 16 words I lose the closing /i and /b tags and that causes my application to malfunction in multiple ways.

My existing code that displays the description.

```php
 <p><?php echo word_limiter($product['description'], 16); ?></p>
```

What would be the best way to automatically close the formatting tags that could be included in the description?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/close-open-html-tags-in-a-string

Comment: I'd advise against manipulating HTML as a string for exactly this reason, if possible I'd recommend using the DOM libraries instead (DOMDocument, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `strip_tags` so that it will remove all HTML tags before rendering.

```
 <p><?php echo strip_tags( word_limiter($product['description'], 16) ); ?></p>
```