# How can i scrape invalid html using php simple dom?

Tags: php, domparser, simpledom

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using phpsimpledom.

```
$html = '<div class="namepageheader"> 
            <div class="u">Name: <a href="someurl">Noor Shaad</a>
            <div class="u">Age: </div>
        </div> ' 
$name=$html->find('div[class="u"]', 0)->innertext;
$age=$html->find('div[class="u"]', 1)->innertext;
```

I tried my best to get text from each `class="u"` but it didn't work because there is missing closing tag `</div>`  on first tag `<div class="u">`. Can anyone help me out with that....

Comment: Do you have to use php simple dom? Have you tried `DOMDocument`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728839/get-element-by-classname-with-domdocument-method for how to implement `getElementsByClassName` with `DOMDocument`.

Comment: that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an element close to where the tag should have been closed and then standardize the html by replacing it.
For example, you can replace the `</a>` tag by `</a></div>`.

```
str_replace('</a>','</a></div>',$html)
```

or if there are too many closed  `</a>` tags , replace  `</a><div class="u">`  with `</a></div><div class="u">`

```
str_replace('</a><div class="u">','</a></div><div class="u">',$html)
```

There may be another problem. There is a gap between the tags and the replacement does not work properly. To solve this problem, you can first delete the spaces between the tags and then replace them.

```
$html = '<div class="namepageheader"> 
            <div class="u">Name: <a href="someurl">Noor Shaad</a>
            <div class="u">Age: </div>
        </div> ' ;
$html = preg_replace('~>\\s+<~m', '><', $html);
str_replace('</a><div class="u">','</a></div><div class="u">',$html);
$name=$html->find('div[class="u"]', 0)->innertext;
$age=$html->find('div[class="u"]', 1)->innertext;
```

Comment: A word of caution -- this solution would work but only for the example given. Unless @user16202411's problem is really predictable, trying to clean it in this way could be prohibitively difficult to debug and maintain.

Comment: Yes,I use this as a quick way to fix and crawl pages that have an invalid html. There are other ways, such as using Tidy or the way mentioned on this page.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/close-open-html-tags-in-a-string )